# email send smtp error on direct admin server

Tags: cakephp, directadmin

I am using Directadmin as hosting for my cakephp website. I have used gmail SMTP to send mail.

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'username' => null,
        'password' => null,
        'client' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
    'gmail' => [
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'username' => 'dummy@gmail.com', //eg: sample[at]gmail.com
        'password' => 'dummypassword', //email password
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => true,
        'client' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

The code is running properly on localhost but it is showing the following error on server

> stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587
> (Network is unreachable)
> please help with the solution

Comment: Weird that the error says it can't connect to port 2525 when your configuration specified port 587.

Comment: I trust that's not your actual email password that you have shown there. If it is, please change it (on GMail, not here) immediately...

Comment: @GregSchmidt Actually the port number was set to 2525 at the time of copying the error message. Was trying different ports at that time which Google was suggesting. 
And yes thats a dummy password. Thank you

Comment: Okay. :-) Have you looked at the many search results on here for php send gmail? Lots of people have this very problem.

Comment: The code is working correctly on localhost but as i upload on directadmin server its showing this error

Comment: Does directadmin allow outgoing SMTP connections from their servers?

Comment: I use host=>smtp.googlemail.com and port=>465 to send email via google and the url line is commented. Hope it will help